# replacing certain characters in string in java

Tags: java

I have a list like this `([... , ... ])` and I want to remove all the spaces and brackets and commas so here is my trail ..

```
String[] Array = lst.toString().split(",");
for(int i=0;i<Array.length;i++){
    System.out.println(Array[i]);
}
```

Comment: Why did you add `mmmmm mmmm`?

Comment: `String.split` takes a regex. Use that to your advantage. Or do it another way, if you would join the string later...

Answer (score 0):

See string [replaceAll](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)) function. You want to replace the specific characters not split

```
     String Str = new String("test,string,");
     System.out.println(Str.replaceAll(",", "" ));
```